# Find word from dictionary in string

Tags: python, json, categorization

I am working a on problem in my project.
I have a DB with column where I have stored types like **"15 mins break"** or **"30 min free time"**
I want to make another column with category.
My categories are stored in dictionary:

```
{ "short":["10","5","15","10min","5min","15min","shorter"],
"middle":["20","25","30","35","20min","25min","30min","35min"],
"long":["40","45","50","55","60","40min","45min","50min","55min","60min"]}
```

Any idea how can I assign category to types using python ?
I mean just that part to find similarity with word in dictionary ?
my code so far

```
...calling sql select
for i, index in rows():
    type = index[0]
    if (any of words from dictionary) is in type:
        category = (name of category, for example "short")
        update in sql
        ...
```

THx

Comment: I do not really get what you want. Can you provide an example with *input* and *output*?

Comment: Do you know the algorithm you want to apply ? If not, this is not the correct place to ask. If so, you should specify it in your question.

Comment: I added pseudocode of my code to better understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find out if *any* of the category markers are in the break description. Suppose `s1` and `s2` are you sample descriptions, and `d` is your dictionary:

```
s1 = "15 mins break"
s2 = "30 min free time"
s3 = "something5something"
```

Then the following expression evaluates to their category (the purpose of `re.findall()` is to tokenize the text; replace the regular expression with whatever is suitable for your project.)

```
[cat for cat in d if any(marker in re.findall(r'[a-z0-9]+',s1) for marker in d[cat])]
#['short']

[cat for cat in d if any(marker in re.findall(r'[a-z0-9]+',s2) for marker in d[cat])]
#['middle']

[cat for cat in d if any(marker in re.findall(r'[a-z0-9]+',s3) for marker in d[cat])]
#[]
```

This assumes that all strings are in the lower case.

Comment: I tried something like this, but it gives me false positive answers.
For example when i look in string like: `s = "something5something"`

Comment: Then you need some sort of a tokenizer, e.g., `re.findall()` (see updated answer) or `nltk.world_tokenize()`.

Comment: Nice thank you, it works.
I am going to study how and why it works.

Ty

Comment: How can I figure out if it is "short", "long" or another key ?

Comment: It's the value of the expression.

Comment: My bad didnt realize, it is too late, Thanks